# Refactoring a binary tree used as a tournament ladder

Tags: c#, algorithm

I created a binary tree that stores information about brackets in a single elimination tournament, the code works as expected, however I think the implementation could be better.

I'm using  `PostOrder` Traversing method to go over the tree and store the information about the teams participating in matchups with help of a delegates, the problem that I would like to get rid of is that I'm using a list of teams `Teams` to assign the team Ids for the matchup, since I can't pass the list of teams as argument for my delegate method I declared the variable in the scope of entire TournamentLadder class.

I wonder if it's possible to avoid this solution and somehow pass the list of teams as an argument for the delegate method or using other way of going around that.

I'm also down for suggestions how to go about creating a tournament like bracket system with binary tree.

Team and Matchup model classes:

```
internal class MatchUpModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<TeamModel> TeamsCompeting { get; set; }
}

public class TeamModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public TeamModel(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }
}
```

Binary Tree Class

```
internal class BinaryTree
{
    internal Node? root;

    internal delegate void  CreateRounds(Node tmproot);

    internal Node RecursiveInsert(Node parent, int e)
    {
        if (parent != null)
        {
            if (e < parent.element)
                parent.left = RecursiveInsert(parent.left, e);
            else if (e > parent.element)
                parent.right = RecursiveInsert(parent.right, e);
        }
        else
        {
            Node n = new Node(e, null, null);
            parent = n;
        }

        return parent;
    }

    internal void PostOrder(Node parent , CreateRounds createRounds)
    {
        if (parent != null)
        {
            PostOrder(parent.left, createRounds);
            PostOrder(parent.right, createRounds);
            createRounds(parent);       
        }
    }
}
```

`TournamentLadder` class:

```
internal static class TournamentLadder
{
    static List<MatchUpModel> matchups = new();
    static internal int numTeams = 16;

    private static List<TeamModel> CreateTeams()
    {
        List<TeamModel> Teams = new();

        for (int i = 1; i <= numTeams; i++)
        {
            Teams.Add(new TeamModel(i));
        }

        return Teams;
    }

    private static List<TeamModel> Teams = CreateTeams();

    private static int CalculateMatchups()
    {   
        int numMatchups = numTeams - 1;
        return numMatchups;
    }

    private static BinaryTree CreateLadder()
    {
        int NumMatchups = CalculateMatchups();

        BinaryTree? ladder = new();
        ladder.root = ladder.RecursiveInsert(ladder.root , 1);

        for (int i = 2; i <= NumMatchups; i++)
        {
            ladder.RecursiveInsert(ladder.root, i);
        }

        return ladder;
    }

    private static void CreateFirstRound(Node tmproot)
    {
        int substractTeams = numTeams - 3;
        
        MatchUpModel mu = new()
        {
            Id = tmproot.element,
            TeamsCompeting = new()
        };

        if (((tmproot.element * 2) - 1 - substractTeams) > 0)
        {
            int team1id = (tmproot.element * 2) - 1 - substractTeams;
            int team2id = (tmproot.element * 2) - 1 - (substractTeams + 1);

            mu.TeamsCompeting.Add(Teams[team1id - 1]);
            mu.TeamsCompeting.Add(Teams[team2id - 1]);
        }
        else
            mu.TeamsCompeting = null;

        Console.Write("Matchup Id: ");
        Console.WriteLine(mu.Id);

        if (mu.TeamsCompeting != null)
        {
            Console.Write("Teams Ids: ");
            Console.Write(mu.TeamsCompeting[0].Id);
            Console.Write(",");
            Console.Write(mu.TeamsCompeting[1].Id);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
    
    internal static void CreateRounds()
    {
        BinaryTree ladder = CreateLadder();
        List<TeamModel> Teams = CreateTeams();

        ladder.PostOrder(ladder.root, CreateFirstRound);
    }

    private static int SimplePower(int x, int pow)
    {
        return (int)Math.Pow(x, pow);
    }
}
```

[Result of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XKfo.png)

Answer (score 2):

I'm having a hard time understanding the requirements. I understand what a tournament bracket is, but the teams only get filled in as games are played, so it's not clear what exactly we need to do here. Just set up the initial tree? So I don't have a lot of feedback currently about how you solve the problem.

1. `SimplePower` is never used, get rid of it.
2. Static classes with state are a huge anti-pattern. Make `TournamentLadder` a normal class with normal member variables.
3. Should `TournamentLadder` be `TournamentBracket`? If not, you need to define a ladder somewhere.
4. `CalculateMatchups` isn't helping anything. Replace it with something like `int numMatchups = NumTeams - 1` and note the casing.
5. Comments and naming are critical! This code is only easily readable if you have already solved the problem yourself. `if (((tmproot.element * 2) - 1 - substractTeams) > 0)` is particularly opaque.

Comment: I managed to find a different solution since then, that for the time being works.

I created teams, then paired them into the matchups. 

To create the structure itself I used queue, foreach matchup I enqueued a new node that had no childrens ( essentially created the binary tree from leafs ), then I created while loop that worked untill there were no elements left in queue, created a new node, and assigns its childrens elements that I dequeued. This way I was able to create the binary tree that in its structure looked exactly like in a Tournament.

Comment: If ur intrested I uploaded the project to github, check the `LadderCreation.cs` for more details about the logic.

https://github.com/numinnex/Tournament-Ladder